# java 8 : Mapper function with dynamic method

Tags: java, lambda

I am trying to make a mapping and get some descriptions. The problem I have is that I don't know how to make mapper function with dynamic parameters.

My code is the following:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class TEST{

     public static String getDesc(String domain, String code){
         String ret = "";
         
         switch(domain){
             case "AAA" :    
                 if(code.equals("0")){
                     ret = "AAA_Descr_0";
                 }else if(code.equals("1")){
                     ret = "AAA_Descr_1";
                 }
             break;

             case "BBB" :    
                 if(code.equals("0")){
                     ret = "BBB_Descr_0";
                 }else if(code.equals("1")){
                     ret = "BBB_Descr_1";
                 }
             break;
         }
         
         return ret;
     }
     
     public static void main(String []args){
       List<String> cities = Arrays.asList("AAA","AAA","BBB", "BBB");
       List<String> codes = Arrays.asList("0","1","0","1");
       List<String> descs = codes.stream()
        .map(code -> getDesc( "AAA", code))
        .distinct()
        .filter(code -> code != null && !code.equals(""))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
       
        descs.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
     }
}
```

How can I replace the line

```java
.map(code -> getDesc( "AAA", code))
```

with something like

```java
.map(code -> getDesc( cities.get(i), code))
```

in order to get all the descs.

Expected output

```
AAA_Descr_0  
AAA_Descr_1  
BBB_Descr_0  
BBB_Descr_1
```

Comment: Can you share the expected output (and explain the logic behind it)?

Comment: would this only apply if both lists are of equal lengths? what happens if they are unequal?

Comment: It's not very clear what you want to achieve, please edit question to explain. From the looks of it you need the combinations of cities and codes, in which case two nested loops would be simpler and more readable.

Comment: The lists have the same number of elements

Comment: I can do it as follow :
   String city, desc;
 List<String> descs = new ArrayList<>();
    int i = 0;
    for (String code : codes ) {

      if (code != null && !code.equals("")) {
        city = cities.get(i);
        desc = getDesc(city, code);

        if (!descs .contains(desc)) {
          descs.add(desc);
        }
      }

      i++;
    }

but is there any way to do it with lambda ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following with IntStream. it streams a range from 0 to size exclusive, then gets each item in the list and provides it as arguments to your function. Not exactly as "dynamic" as you expect, but its as good as it gets

```
public static void main(String []args){
   List<String> cities = Arrays.asList("AAA","AAA","BBB", "BBBB");
   List<String> codes = Arrays.asList("0","1","0","1");
   
   List<String> descs = IntStream.range(0, cities.size())
           .mapToObj(i -> getDesc(cities.get(i), codes.get(i)))
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
//       List<String> descs = codes.stream()
//        .map(code -> getDesc( "AAA", code))
//        .distinct()
//        .filter(code -> code != null && !code.equals(""))
//        .collect(Collectors.toList());
   
    descs.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
 }
```

output:

```
AAA_Descr_0
AAA_Descr_1
BBB_Descr_0
```